# How to combine the character list vectors into one character vector while keeping the contents of each list unchanged

Tags: r, string, list, merge

I get a list of characters which have different lengths, I want to merge these element of it into one character vector. that is :
the input is: 
`input=list("a", c( "b" , "b" ),c( "c" , "c" , "c" )`
the output which I wanted is: 
`output=c( "a" , "b" , "b" , "c" , "c" , "c" )`
I have searched on the web , which mostly got the result as :
`the_result_not_wanted=c( "a", "b b" , "c c c" )`,but this is not what I wanted.
What can I do? Would you kindly help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: `unlist(input)`

Comment: yes, "unlist" works! Thank you for your kindness!